# Error installing mysql workbench in Ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-16.04

I'm having a problem installing mysql workbench on UBUNTU 16.04 lts when trying to install, it returns the error saying I do not have any dependencies on python, but I also can not install the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench : Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
                   Depends: python-mysql.connector but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-paramiko but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-pexpect but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

see that it asks for python> = 2.6.6, and I have python in version 2.7.12

```
python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

I noticed that some python dependencies are missing too, I try to install python PIP and I get the following error.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-pip : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
              Recommends: python-all-dev (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Note that again it complains about the python version, but the version I matched with the required one, as it asks <2.8 and> = 2.7.5

I thought it might be getting Python 3 that was already installed on ubuntu, which other applications use, but I do not believe it. Here are some installed python identification commands.

```
11442:/usr/bin$ ls -la | grep python

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root               26 Set 21 11:10 dh_pypy -> ../share/dh-python/dh_pypy
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root               29 Set 21 11:10 dh_python3 -> ../share/dh-python/dh_python3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root               23 Nov 19  2016 pdb2.7 -> ../lib/python2.7/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root               23 Set 18 12:59 pdb3.5 -> ../lib/python3.5/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root               31 Set 21 11:10 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root               26 Set 21 11:10 pybuild -> ../share/dh-python/pybuild
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root               24 Out 11 18:23 python -> /etc/alternatives/python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root    root          3546104 Nov 19  2016 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root                9 Out 11 17:54 python3 -> python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x  1 diegodr domain^users  4460336 Nov 17  2016 python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root    root          4456240 Set 18 12:59 python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root               10 Set 21 11:10 python3m -> python3.5m

11442:/usr/local/bin$ ls -la | grep python

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Out 11 18:17 python -> /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       9 Out  9 13:11 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 8287232 Out 11 17:23 python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    1687 Out 11 17:23 python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Out  9 13:11 python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      14 Out  9 13:11 python-config -> python2-config


11442:~$ whereis python

python: /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.5 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.5 /etc/python /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.5m /usr/share/python

11442:~$ which python

/usr/local/bin/python
```

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Note: neither the terminator I can install, gives the same problem regarding the dependencies of python.

```
11442:~$ sudo apt-get install terminator

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 terminator : Depends: python-dbus but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python-gobject but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python-gtk2 (>= 2.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python-vte but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
              Recommends: python-gnome2 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-keybinder but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-notify but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Comment: Did not work.
Accuse the same mistake.

Comment: After several failed attempts, the solution was to format the PC